# How to override any operator if the first operand isn't your object

Tags: kotlin

I gave Kotlin a try, because it's supposed to be a java without certain limitations like checked exceptions or no support for operator overriding (of course these limitations got their right to exists, like reduction of abusing or forced verbosity, but this question isn't why they should (not) exist). So I wrote a simple `Vector2` class, which should support basic operators like +-*/.

There isn't a problem when your first and second operand both are from the type `Vector2`, but there is a problem when the first operand isn't from type `Vector2`. Take this example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val vector = Vector2(2.0, 3.0) * 2.0
}
```

This works flawless because of this method in `Vector2`:

```
operator fun times(d: Double) = Vector2(x * d, y * d)
```

But what am I supposed to do if the two operands change place like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val vector = 2.0  * Vector2(2.0, 3.0)
}
```

I though of an operator overload of `times()` for the type `Double`:

```
// In 'Vector2.kt'
operator fun Double.times(vector: Vector2) = ...
```

but I don't know how to retrieve the double value to multiply it with the vector.

Could anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html), the receiver (the object the function is called on) is always available as `this`, in the body of your implementation.

```
operator fun Double.times(vector: Vector2): Vector2 = vector * this
```

You could implement that any way you'd like, I just reversed the operands to shorten the example.